# In a VS Setup project, how can I exclude the dependencies of a project from the MSI?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, ilmerge

I'm working in C#.  I have a small VS Solution with 4 projects:

1. a DLL
2. an EXE that references the DLL
3. a merge project, that does nothing more than ILMerge on the assemblies from the prior two steps
4. a setup project, that packages the .EXE output of the Merge project.  (I've added the "Primary Output of a Project" to the setup, specifying the Merge project here)

The problem is, the setup project automatically detects the projects #1 and #2 as dependencies for project #3.  When I include the primary output of the 3rd project into the MSI (Setup project), the dependencies are automatically dragged in as well.  I don't want this.

How can I stop it?

I tried specifying an "Exclude Filter" but couldn't get that to work. No matter what I tried, the dependencies always got dragged in.

[image]

I tried manually modifying the Setup.vdproj, to remove the auto-detected dependency projects, but when I re-loaded the .vdproj in VS, the auto-detected dependencies came back.

help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I hate when that happens.  I figured it out 3 minutes after I asked the question.

You can just right click on the detected dependencies, and in the properties window, specify "Exclude = True"

[image]

Comment: But can it be removed completely?

Answer (score 1):

Awesome Cheeso that worked for me.  Just be careful that if one of your projects or sub projects gets a new project reference then that dependancy will appear in the setup project. You will have to be aware of this and exclude the dependancy as you have done.

Comment: And some dependencies keep self-enabling when switching build configurations :(